# switch between blobs to get content as email attachment in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a design in logic app which sends email with attachment when called from a pipeline in ADF. Attachment is the file Pipeline writes in the blob storage. Below is the design.

[image]

I created the pipeline in dev ADF and moved it to prod ADF. In dev adf pipeline copies data to dev blob and prod pipleine copies to prod blob. But logic app get blob content steps connects to dev blob. How can I switch blob from connecting to dev or prod as required.

Comment: The change connection button?!? You need to have a LogicApp for dev AND another for prod. You can’t change the connection during runtime. The only way you could do that nicely is to use REST API’s via the HTTP connector.

Comment: Are you using two logic apps - one for Dev and one for Prod? Can you share your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have to different storage account using logic app [blob connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/) based on the input of your HTTP trigger as there is no way to set the connector authentication dynamically during the run time.

The alternative would be creating two different logic apps for your dev and production. In case if you want to create two different logic app then you cannot leverage the blob connector. Instead of using blob connector you need to leverage the [Native HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) and call the [storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/) so you can dynamically create the URL and set the authentication.